# « Lors de », « durant » ou « pendant » ?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire

Quand doit-on utiliser l'un plutôt que l'autre ? Existe-t-il une différence ?

--

When should I use one versus another? Is there any difference, in form or function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Les premières acceptions du nouveau petit Robert :

> - pendant : exprime la simultanéité (avec un terme qui désigne l'espace    de temps où l'action, le fait à lieu).
> - durant : pendant la durée  de.
> - lors de : au moment de à l'époque

Il y a donc des distinctions assez subtiles, selon que l'on veuille insister 
. sur la durée (*durant* l'été) d'une action ou d'un fait,
. sur la simultanéité (médicament à prendre *pendant* les repas) d'une action à effectuer
. sur la concomitance des événements (*lors de* son mariage).

Answer (score 2):

À mon sens, on peut employer indifféremment `pendant` et `durant` qui ont sensiblement la même signification. Ils expriment tous deux une notion de durée.
Pour ce qui est de `lors de`, ceci exprime plutôt une idée de simultanéité de deux évènements.